# WorkManager periodic request not runnning?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am trying to run an api call periodically every one hour. I know the minimum time interval for periodic request is 15 minutes i have definitely kept it more than that.

Below is my code to run periodic request

```
val data = Data.Builder().putString(
            "covid_country",
            viewModel?.getSavedCountry()
        ).build()

        val request =
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CovidWorker::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInputData(data)
            .setConstraints(
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()


        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("simplified", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request)
```

In the `workmanager` class's `doWork` method i am just calling the api and send local notification if successfully.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
        val covidCountry = inputData.getString("covid_country")
        Log.i("savedd112", covidCountry)
        Coroutines.main {

            val response =
                CovidApi().getCovidCases("india")

            val count = response?.get(response.size - 1)?.Cases ?: 0
            Log.i("hereeached", "mark")
            displayNotification("Cases in india", "$count")


        }
        return Result.retry()
    }
```

But it is never runned. I dont see my local notification. I waited the whole day for this. There is no easy way to debug this so i decided to convert my periodic work request to one time work request and added a button in my `UI` and on the button on click listener i called the following code

```
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(request)
```

Now the api gets called correctly and the local notification is displayed when the `api` succeeds. I dont understand why my periodic request is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured it out

Instead of using

```
ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP
```

use this

```
ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE
```